# Using Lan and Wlan at the same time (Concurrently)?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan, ethernet

There are two internet account. One is connected to a pc with ethernet cable. The other one is connected to same pc with wireless.

Is it possible to use them concurrently?

Example:

1. acc 1 : 8 mbit
2. acc 2 : 16 mbit

acc 1 + acc 2 = 24 mbit.

cable and wireless connected directly to motherboard.

If this is not possible, can I force an application to use wlan ?

OS: Windows 7

Comment: [network bridge](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-network-bridge#1TC=windows-7), but I'm not sure if it works the way you expect it to.

Comment: tried bridging. But the speed not increased.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bridge two different internet connections](http://superuser.com/questions/456328/how-to-bridge-two-different-internet-connections), http://superuser.com/questions/417673/internet-connection-using-2-modem-at-a-time, http://superuser.com/questions/147459/is-it-possible-to-combine-the-bandwidth-from-a-dsl-modem-and-a-clearwire-modem

Comment: For question 2: [How can I force certain applications to use specific network connections?](http://superuser.com/questions/74389/how-can-i-force-certain-applications-to-use-specific-network-connections?rq=1), [Force an application to use a specific network interface](http://superuser.com/questions/181882/force-an-application-to-use-a-specific-network-interface), etc.

Comment: You can force an application to us wireless lan, but the faster internet speeds will not add up, you either have to use one or another at a time.